# Absolute convergence of $\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}e^{-n\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Exercise**: Study the absolute convergence and convergence domains of the following series:
>   $$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}e^{-n\sin x}$$

I tried to solve it in the following way:

**My resolution:**

*Convergence*:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}(-1)^{n+1}e^{-n\sin x}=0$ So by the Leibniz criterion the series converge for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

*Absolute convergence*:$\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^{n+1}e^{-n\sin x}|=\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}|(-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{e^{n\sin x}}|\leqslant\sum_\limits{n=1}^{\infty}|\frac{1}{e^{n\sin x}}|$
By the integral test $\int_\limits{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{e^{n\sin x}} dn=\frac{1}{\sin x e^{\sin x}}<\infty$ 
So the series converge absolutely $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

**Solution(book):** The series converge absolutely if $2k\pi<x<(2k+1)\pi\:\:\forall k\in \mathbb{Z}$, in all other points the series diverge.

**Questions:**

I was puzzled by the books solution. What have I done wrong?

How should I study the absolute convergence then?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that when $x=\pi k$ then $\sin x=\sin \pi k=0$  for any $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence the series would be
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}e^{-n\sin x}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}e^{-n\sin \pi k}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}$$
which is not convergent.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you think of the comparison test I used on absolute convergence? Why is it wrong?

Comment: even in comparison test if $\sin x=0$ the integral diverges.